# JSF -- <ui:repeat /> over a java.util.Set?

Tags: jsf

Does the `<ui:repeat />` tag support iterating over a `java.util.Set`?  I've tried iterating over my JPA domain entity objects contained in a Set, but receive errors.  Is there something I'm missing?  Does an additional flag need to be present or something?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

No, the `ui:repeat` does not support Set, nor does `h:dataTable`.

You should return a List from the Set, and use that instead.

```
public List<T> getListFromSet(Set<T> set) {
  return new ArrayList<T>(set);
}
```

You should avoid using `c:forEach`; [here is an article on why](https://rogerkeays.com/jsf-c-foreach-vs-ui-repeat).

Comment: Since getters in JSF are usally called [several times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times) this can be an expensive solution.

Answer (score 76):

The easiest way to finish the deal at page without modifying the class is converting the `set` to an `array` like this.

```
<ui:repeat value="#{myBean.mySet.toArray()}" var="_myvar">
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `c:forEach` instead. It appears that `ui:repeat` does not support sets (i.e. requires some sort of ordering property).

Otherwise you can create your own tag as described in:
http://techblog.bozho.net/?p=28

Comment: Do **NOT** consider using `c:forEach`: http://www.ilikespam.com/blog/c:foreach-vs-ui:repeat-in-facelets

Comment: It completely depends on what the set is that you are iterating over and if it compile time or not. So if that is the case then you CAN use `c:forEach`.

Comment: Yes if you know what you are doing, then you can use `c:forEach`, but I read your post as that `you should consider using c:forEach`, and this is not the case. Better using `ui:repeat` to avoid problems

Comment: @Shervin updated link: https://rogerkeays.com/jsf-c-foreach-vs-ui-repeat